# Phantom wallet extension URL?

Tags: phantom, solana-sdk

I am currently developing a Unity game with a component in it that allows you to log in to the game using the Phantom Wallet extension. However, I have been unsuccessful in finding the **Phanton Wallet extension URL**

Does anyone know the exact URL address for the Phantom Wallet extension?

Comment: Would be helpful if you add the unity sdk version you are using.

Comment: what do you mean the "wallet extension url"?
as in the place to install the extension? or the url that a user sees when they open the extension in their browser?

Answer (score 1):

in the unity sdk all you need to do is use the PhantomWallet and call Login.

```
    private async void LoginCheckerPhantom()
    {
        var account = await Web3.Instance.LoginPhantom();
        CheckAccount(account);
    }
```

Here is any example from the magic block unity sdk:
[https://github.com/magicblock-labs/Solana.Unity-SDK/blob/main/Samples~/Solana%20Wallet/Scripts/example/screens/LoginScreen.cs](https://github.com/magicblock-labs/Solana.Unity-SDK/blob/main/Samples%7E/Solana%20Wallet/Scripts/example/screens/LoginScreen.cs)

In webgl it uses the injected provider via window.phantom and on mobile the deeplink url:

`https://phantom.app/ul/\<version>/\<method>`

Deeplink specifications of phantom you can see here:
https://docs.phantom.app/phantom-deeplinks/deeplinks-ios-and-android

Also the unity sdk supports the wallet adapter now. So maybe give that a try instead of using phantom directly.